# UITableView space on top in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a grouped `UITableView` in XIB. When loaded its showing extra space on top of first section header.

What I have tried so far:

```
   if #available(iOS 11, *) {
  self.recordTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
   //Doesn't Work
  //self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
  self.parent?.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

}
```

Also tried setting tableView -> Content Insets to Never in XIB.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe you have added an extra header view in storyboard to your UITableView? @icodes

Comment: you tableView style is Plain or Grouped? you can check this from Inspector of storyboard

Comment: I am using grouped tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you will need to understand two things. Setting zero height of TableHeaderView and SectionHeaderHight

1. This will set your Table Header Height to zero

   tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude)))
2. This will set section header hight (NOTE : YOU might not need this. Depends on your use case)

   tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude